# How to build vue component library with vite and tailwind? (tailwind classes not working when importing to other project)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, vite

## Current

I have two repositories:

- Main Web App - simple nuxt3 web app
- Component Library - simple vite/vue app

## Goal

Build my own component library using vite, vue3 and tailwindcss

## Problem

When I use `npm run dev` I can se my components working fine (from the vite app) but when I build my library `npm run build:watch` and import them in another project (nuxt app) tailwind classes/styles are not working

This is mi vite app (all good)

[image: Vite App with a red button]

This is the nuxt app where I imported the component (no style)

[image: Nuxt App with the smae button but no color]

---

Repositories:

- Main Web App: https://github.com/fro-systems/clau-web
- Component Library: https://github.com/fro-systems/clau-components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this to `package.json` on the vite-libray

```
"exports": {
    "./dist/style.css": "./dist/style.css"
  },
```

And addin this `nuxt.config.ts`

```
css: [
  "clau-components/dist/style.css"
],
```

The issues was that I wasn't adding the styles

Comment: Can I ask if there is a way to fix this **without explicitly importing css in the host project** (in this case, `nuxt.config.ts`)? Cos if we have a lot of custom libraries then importing the bundled css is going to need a lot of manual work. Pls advice if I should post a separate qn

Comment: Were you are to resolve this without an explicit import to the host project?